# Insert dummy rows to fill missing values into a SQL Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, database-design, user-defined-functions

I have this SQL Server table `table1` which I want to fill with dummy rows per acct up to latest previous month end date period e.g now would be up to 2021-06-30.

In this example, acct 1 has n number of rows which ends at 2020-05-31, and I want to insert dummy rows with same values for `acct` and `amt` with `begin_date` and `end_date` incrementing by 1 month up to 06-30-2021.

Let's assume `acct` 2 already ends at 06-30-2021 so this doesn't need dummy rows to be inserted.

```
 acct,amt,begin_date,end_date
  1 , 10, 2020-04-01, 2020-04-30
  1 , 10, 2020-05-01, 2020-05-31
  2 , 50, 2021-05-01, 2021-05-31
  2 , 50, 2021-06-01, 2021-06-30
```

So for acct 1, I want n number of rows to be inserted from last period of 2020-05-31 up to previous month end which is now 06-30-2021 and I want the amt and acct to remain same. So it would look like this below:

```
    acct,amt,begin_date,end_date
      1 , 10, 2020-04-01, 2020-04-30
      1 , 10, 2020-05-01, 2020-05-31
      1 , 10, 2020-06-01, 2020-06-30
      1 , 10, 2020-07-01, 2020-07-31
      .............................
      .............................
      1 , 10, 2021-06-01, 2021-06-30
```

Based on some data anamolies, I realize I need another condition to the solution. Suppose another column `type` was added to the `table1`. So `acct` and `type` would be the composite key that identifies each related row hence acct 2 type A and acct 2 type B are not related. So we have the updated table:

```
 acct,type,amt,begin_date,end_date
  1,  A,   10, 2020-04-01, 2020-04-30
  1,  A,   10, 2020-05-01, 2020-05-31
  2,  A,   50, 2021-05-01, 2021-05-31
  2,  A,   50, 2021-06-01, 2021-06-30
  2,  B,   50, 2021-01-01, 2021-01-31
  2,  B,   50, 2021-02-01, 2021-02-28
```

I would now need dummy rows to be created for acct 2 type B up to 2021-06-30. We already know acct 2 type A would be ok since it already has rows up to 2021-06-30

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. DDL helps us help you, e.g. what data type should we guess the "dates" are? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the rows using a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select acct, amt,
             dateadd(day, 1, end_date) as begin_date,
             eomonth(dateadd(day, 1, end_date)) as end_date
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by acct order by end_date desc) as seqnum
            from t
           ) t
      where seqnum = 1 and end_date < '2021-06-30'
      union all
      select acct, amt, dateadd(month, 1, begin_date),
             eomonth(dateadd(month, 1, begin_date))
      from cte
      where begin_date < '2021-06-01'
     )
select *
from cte;
```

You can then use `insert` to insert these rows into a table.  Or use `union all` if you simply want a result set with all the rows.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=92b5bb7e478bebc688617b4e0da0a749) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hi @GordonLintoff, Can you see my updated question please. Based on some data anamolies, I need some furthur changes to solution.

Comment: @JaxonX . . . Ask a new question in that case.