# Create dummy rows to fill missing values into a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-order-by, common-table-expression, recursive-query

This question is in addition to my previous post: [Insert dummy rows to fill missing values into a SQL Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68328262/insert-dummy-rows-to-fill-missing-values-into-a-sql-table)

I have this SQL Server table; I want to fill with n number of missing rows with dummy data up to the previous month end, which at this time would be 2021-06-30. I want the other columns `acct, type, amt` to be the same with `begin_date` and `end_date` incrementing by 1 month up to 2021-06-30.

For example: acct 2 type B ends at period 2021-02-28, hence I need dummy rows to be created from this date up to the end of the previous month end which as of now is 2021-06-30.

`acct 2 type A` already has rows up to the previous months end `2021-06-30` hence no dummy rows are needed.

```
 acct,type,amt, begin_date, end_date
  1,  C,   10, 2020-05-01, 2020-05-31
  1,  C,   10, 2020-06-01, 2020-06-30
  2,  B,   50 ,2021-01-01, 2021-01-31
  2,  B,   50 ,2021-02-01, 2021-02-28
  2,  A,   50 ,2021-05-01, 2021-05-31
  2,  A,   50 ,2021-06-01, 2021-06-30
```

This is how I want the result:

```
      acct,type,amt, begin_date, end_date
      1,  C,   10, 2020-05-01, 2020-05-31
      1,  C,   10, 2020-06-01, 2020-06-30
      ....................................
      1,  C,   10, 2021-06-01, 2021-06-30
      2,  B,   50 ,2021-01-01, 2021-01-31
      2,  B,   50 ,2021-02-01, 2021-02-28
      2,  B,   50 ,2021-03-01, 2021-03-31
      2,  B,   50 ,2021-04-01, 2021-04-30
      2,  B,   50 ,2021-05-01, 2021-05-31
      2,  B,   50 ,2021-06-01, 2021-06-30
```

Then I would be able to do a `insert` to the original table or a `union all`

Comment: This is why you'd have a numbers table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your data, 1/C ends a year before the date you have in mind.  So, it should also generate rows.

I see the difference from your previous question:

- You have `acct`/`type` together.
- The cutoff date is dynamic based on the current date.

The changes are really just tweaks on the earlier query:

```
with cte as (
      select acct, type, amt,
             dateadd(day, 1, end_date) as begin_date,
             eomonth(dateadd(day, 1, end_date)) as end_date
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by acct, type order by end_date desc) as seqnum
            from t
           ) t
      where seqnum = 1 and end_date < eomonth(getdate(), -2)
      union all
      select acct, type, amt, dateadd(month, 1, begin_date),
             eomonth(dateadd(month, 1, begin_date))
      from cte
      where begin_date < eomonth(getdate(), -2)
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=95d73878b7fc59f8d67ece71cbab965a) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff, your a real guru. I myself just saw that I didnt end 1/C  with 2021-06-30 in my explanation and you picked it up. Thanks, again your a real specialist in wrangling data.

Comment: @GordonIinoff, I see from the fiddle results It generated up to 2021-07-31 and not 2021-06-30. I'll just modify the date subtraction in where clause.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers table comment aside, if your table contains all the dates on it somewhere (in any row) you could patch up your data with some cross joining

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT begin_date, end_date FROM x) a
  CROSS JOIN
  SELECT DISTINCT acct, type, amt FROM x) b
```

If the data cannot be relied upon to have every distinct date, create a numbers/calendar table and left join onto it

Might also be worth checking out if your SQL Server has the `EOMONTH` function; could help you ditch end date